# SOLR and Ratio of Matching Words

Tags: apache, search, solr

Using SOLR version 4.3, it appears that SOLR is valuing the percentage of matching terms more than the number of matching terms.

For example, we do a search for Dog and a document with just the word dog and a three other words returns. We have another article with hundreds of words, that has the word dog in it 27 times.

I would expect the second article to return first. However, the one with one word out of three returns first. I was hoping to find out what in SOLR controls this so I can make the appropriate modifications. I have looked the SOLR documentation and have seen COORD mentioned, but it seems to indicate that the article with 27 references should return first. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For 4.x Solr still used regular TF/IDF as its scoring formula, and you can see the Lucene implementation [detailed in the documentation for TFIDFSimilarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

For your question, the two factors that affect the score is:

The length of the field, as given in `norm()`:

> norm(t,d) encapsulates a few (indexing time) boost and length factors:
>
> - Field boost - set by calling field.setBoost() before adding the field to a document.
> - lengthNorm - computed when the document is added to the index in accordance with the number of tokens of this field in the document, so that shorter fields contribute more to the score. LengthNorm is computed by the Similarity class in effect at indexing.

.. while the number of terms matching (not their frequency), is given by `coord()`:

> coord(q,d) is a score factor based on how many of the query terms are found in the specified document. Typically, a document that contains more of the query's terms will receive a higher score than another document with fewer query terms. This is a search time factor computed in coord(q,d) by the Similarity in effect at search time.

There are [a few settings in your schema that can affect how Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html#DefiningFields-OptionalFieldTypeOverrideProperties) scores the documents in your example:

> **omitNorms**
>
> If true, omits the norms associated with this field (this disables length normalization for the field, and saves some memory)

.. this will remove the norm() part of the score.

> **omitTermFreqAndPositions**
>
> If true, omits term frequency, positions, and payloads from postings for this field.

.. and this will remove the boost from multiple occurrences of the same term. Be aware that this will remove positions as well, making phrase queries impossible.

But you should also consider upgrading Solr, as the BM25 similarity that's the default from 6.x usually performs better. I can't remember if a version is available for 4.3.